# Check current set date of origin in R

Tags: r, date

is there a way we can check a date column's origin date ?

```
as.Date(x, **origin** = , ...)
```

So that we can use this and accordingly define other numeric date columns. 
To add to that, does it even matter if the origin dates are different ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. R converts and stores all Dates relative to the default origin, whatever you specify:

```
identical(as.Date(99,origin="2013-01-02"),as.Date(100,origin="2013-01-01"))
[1] TRUE

as.numeric(as.Date(99,origin="2013-01-02"))
[1] 15806
as.numeric(as.Date(100,origin="2013-01-01"))
[1] 15806
```